# Module parse failed: Unexpected token / swagger-ui

Tags: webpack, next.js, node-modules, swagger-ui

Our repository has been running swagger-ui with no issues, but without any changes being made, I am now receiving an error and unable to update the repo at all. The build fails during deployment and I receive this error:

```
./node_modules/swagger-ui-react/swagger-ui.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> .swagger-ui{color:#3b4151;
```

I have tried incorporating loader in a webpack.config.js file and I installed the css loader via npm. I've tried a few different set-ups and none of them have solved the issue- I get the same error. Here are three configs I've tried:

Config 1

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: 'swagger-ui',
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
    ],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
    },
  },
};
```

Config 2

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: 'babel', query: { presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1'] } },
          { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
        ]
      },
};
```

Config 3

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Could anyone please let me know what I might be missing? I [raised an issue on the github](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/8062) swagger-ui repo a few days ago with no response and this is my first time using a loader so help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It turned out that the issue was actually the serverless dependency and aws settings. Why it resulted in the error above, I'm not exactly sure!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).